# How to remove lines from park poi in google maps

Tags: reactjs, google-maps, next.js, google-maps-api-3

[google-maps/api](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@react-google-maps/api) with Next.JS.

I've tried to remove til lines from the parks, but nothing seems to work. I think it might be paths inside the parks.

I read all from https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/style-reference without luck to remove theese paths. Does anyone have a clue to remove them?

See image for refference. There are red arrows pointing to the paths im taling abou[image]

My

```
const styles: Record<string, google.maps.MapTypeStyle[]> = {
      default: [],
      hide: [
        {
          featureType: "poi.business",
          stylers: [{ visibility: "off" }],
        },

        {
          featureType: "all",
          elementType: "geometry.stroke",
          stylers: [{ visibility: "off" }],
        },
        {
          featureType: "poi.attraction",
          stylers: [{ visibility: "off" }],
        },
        {
          featureType: "poi.government",
          stylers: [{ visibility: "off" }],
        },
        {
          featureType: "poi.place_of_worship",
          stylers: [{ visibility: "off" }],
        },
        {
          featureType: "poi.medical",
          stylers: [{ visibility: "off" }],
        },
        {
          featureType: "poi.school",
          stylers: [{ visibility: "off" }],
        },

        {
          featureType: "administrative.locality",
          elementType: "labels.text.fill",
          stylers: [{ visibility: "on" }, { color: "#63959F" }],
        },

        {
          featureType: "administrative.country",
          elementType: "labels.text.fill",
          stylers: [{ visibility: "on" }, { color: "#63959F" }],
        },

        {
          featureType: "poi.park",
          elementType: "geometry.fill",
          stylers: [{ visibility: "on" }, { color: "#BBE5CF" }],
        },
        {
          featureType: "poi.park",
          elementType: "labels.text",
          stylers: [{ visibility: "off" }],
        },
        {
          featureType: "transit",
          elementType: "labels.icon",
          stylers: [
            { visibility: "on" },
            { color: "#976D51" },
            { saturation: 0 },
            { lightness: 0 },
          ],
        },
        {
          featureType: "transit",
          elementType: "labels.text",
          stylers: [{ visibility: "off" }],
        },
        {
          featureType: "water",
          elementType: "geometry",
          stylers: [{ color: "#C8ECED" }, { visibility: "on" }],
        },
        {
          featureType: "water",
          elementType: "labels.text",
          stylers: [{ visibility: "off" }],
        },
        // {
        //   featureType: "transit",
        //   elementType: "geometry.fill",
        //   stylers: [
        //     { hue: main_color },
        //     { visibility: "on" },
        //     { lightness: brightness_value },
        //     { saturation: saturation_value },
        //   ],
        // },
      ],
    };
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those paths are categorized under `road.local` and are rendered under `geometry.fill`. Setting these to hidden will hide these paths, but it will also hide some other local roads that are filled.

```
const styles: Record<string, google.maps.MapTypeStyle[]> = {
      default: [],
      hide: [
        {
          featureType: "poi.business",
          stylers: [{ visibility: "off" }],
        },

        {
          featureType: "all",
          elementType: "geometry.stroke",
          stylers: [{ visibility: "off" }],
        },
        {
          featureType: "poi.attraction",
          stylers: [{ visibility: "off" }],
        },
        {
          featureType: "poi.government",
          stylers: [{ visibility: "off" }],
        },
        {
          featureType: "poi.place_of_worship",
          stylers: [{ visibility: "off" }],
        },
        {
          featureType: "poi.medical",
          stylers: [{ visibility: "off" }],
        },
        {
          featureType: "poi.school",
          stylers: [{ visibility: "off" }],
        },

        {
          featureType: "administrative.locality",
          elementType: "labels.text.fill",
          stylers: [{ visibility: "on" }, { color: "#63959F" }],
        },

        {
          featureType: "administrative.country",
          elementType: "labels.text.fill",
          stylers: [{ visibility: "on" }, { color: "#63959F" }],
        },

        {
          featureType: "poi.park",
          elementType: "geometry.fill",
          stylers: [{ visibility: "on" }, { color: "#BBE5CF" }],
        },
        {
          featureType: "poi.park",
          elementType: "labels.text",
          stylers: [{ visibility: "off" }],
        },
        {
          featureType: "transit",
          elementType: "labels.icon",
          stylers: [
            { visibility: "on" },
            { color: "#976D51" },
            { saturation: 0 },
            { lightness: 0 },
          ],
        },
        {
          featureType: "transit",
          elementType: "labels.text",
          stylers: [{ visibility: "off" }],
        },
        {
          featureType: "water",
          elementType: "geometry",
          stylers: [{ color: "#C8ECED" }, { visibility: "on" }],
        },
        {
          featureType: "water",
          elementType: "labels.text",
          stylers: [{ visibility: "off" }],
        },
        // {
        //   featureType: "transit",
        //   elementType: "geometry.fill",
        //   stylers: [
        //     { hue: main_color },
        //     { visibility: "on" },
        //     { lightness: brightness_value },
        //     { saturation: saturation_value },
        //   ],
        // },
        
        {
          featureType: "road.local",
          elementType: "geometry.fill",
          stylers: [{ visibility: "off" }],
        }
      ],
    };
```

Google Maps provides a tool that allows you to style maps using JSON. The newer variant of this is using cloud based map identifiers, but they still have a legacy option (Use the legacy JSON styling wizard): https://mapstyle.withgoogle.com/

[image: Google Maps Platform tool]

You can find this setting under Road > Local > Geometry > Fill. On the top right, you can search for Copenhagen to see changes in real time to that specific area.

Comment: Please do not share code in a code snippet if the code cannot be run.

Comment: @MrUpsidown Okay sorry. My bad.